# How to redirect on previous to previous page in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am a newbie to `wordpress`. I am currently working on registration and login. I have a page restrict url let `http://xyz.com/abc`. Login/registration is required for this url.

I need that when a user register or login then it should be redirected on this previous url.

In login I have added the following hook :

a

```
add_filter('login_redirect', 'redirect_previous_page', 10);

function redirect_previous_page(){

    global $user;
    $request = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];

    if ( in_array( $user->roles[0], array( 'administrator') ) ) {

        return admin_url();
        return $redirect_to;

    } elseif ( in_array( $user->roles[0], array( 'subscriber') ) ) {

        return $request;
        return $redirect_to;

    } 

}
```

It is working for me, but I am not getting how can I redirect on this url after successful registration. I have registration link on the login page

Answer (score 10):

As mentioned in the [**docs**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_referer), you can use: **`<?php wp_get_referer() ?>`** to get the last URL visited by user, before logout or after login.

Comment: Yes - if there is a "wp_" way then use it I say!

Answer (score 9):

```
if ( (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] != 'logout') || (isset($_POST['login_location']) && !empty($_POST['login_location'])) ) {
    add_filter('login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect', 10, 3);
    function my_login_redirect() {
        $location = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
        wp_safe_redirect($location);
        exit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is rough way but, you can create `$_SESSION['your_registration_referrer']` paste there your `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]` and after registration redirect to this url.

Comment: I am using theme-my-login plugin, so where should I put the code to read it ?

Answer (score 0):

> I need that when a user register or login then it should be redirected on this previous url.

If you don`t need permanent redirect for some page you can use redirect in `wp_login_url()`

```
// current page with get parameters
$redirect_after_login = home_url( add_query_arg( null, null ) ); 
// or just
$redirect_after_login = get_the_permalink();
$link_to_login = wp_login_url( $redirect_after_login );
```

Than you can use this link in `wp_safe_redirect()` or just echo somewhere

And here is the corrected code for the redirect after login:

```
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'redirect_previous_page', 10, 1 );
function redirect_previous_page( $redirect_to ) {
    // don't change url if current user is admin or if user inside admin page
    if ( is_admin() || current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ) {
        return $redirect_to;
    }
    // also, we can check is current user has some role
    // if (current_user_can( 'subscriber' ))
    
    // change redirect url to previus page for non-administrators
    $redirect_to= wp_get_referer();

    // referer can return 'false' so add fallback
    return $redirect_to ? $redirect_to : home_url();
}
```

P.S. Unfortunately, no one wrote about the two "returns". The second "return" don`t send because is unattainable